# Problems compiling Eigen in Objective-C (not iPhone)

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, compiler-construction, eigen

I'm trying to compile the Eigen 3 library in an Objective-C++ XCode project (for Mac OSX), and it outputs more than 200 errors, like if it was a linker error. I put a picture below to show the first errors output.

My project is using Objective-C and C++ (a Bullet Physics implem actually) so I

- renamed all my files with the .mm extension,
- checked the "Compile as Objective-C++" in the project settings,
- tried to change the type of the "special" Eigen headers (without extensions) to different types,

but nothing worked...

The `#import` in my program file is working well, as I can see that XCode recognize my

`Matrix4f eigenViewMatrix = Map<Matrix4f>(viewMatrix, 4, 4);`

I guess there is a flag to add, but I can't find what and where. By the way, I'm using the LLVM GCC 4.2 compiler.

I would be really grateful to receive some help. Thank you.

[image]

---

**EDIT**

I enabled OpenMP and SSE in the project Build Settings, like in this post : http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=98401

I can't find "auto-vectorization" though.

If I include the

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Core>
#include <Dense>
```

in the implementation file (.mm) I have less errors than if it is included in a global header file. The errors only concern Block.h and Memory.h now.

Comment: You gave a line that is working well, can you put up a line that isn't working well?  You might need to include more things from Eigen but it's hard to say with the output you've given

Comment: I have no lines not working. That's the only line in my program for the moment. I don't know what to give you so you can understand. Right now I enabled OpenMP and SSE like found in this post : http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=98401 but no way... I can show the structure of my files may be...

Answer (score 2):

Well, after empiric tests I finally found that Eigen headers calls had to be **before** everything.

In my Prefix Header (.pch) I had some calls, and so I finally change it like this :

```
//
// Prefix header for all source files of the 'h[Oz] Bullet' target in the 'h[Oz] Bullet' project
//

#ifdef __OBJC__
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <Core>
#include <Dense>

#import <Quartz/Quartz.h>
#import <OpenGL/CGLMacro.h>
#import <OpenGL/gluMacro.h>
```

Hope it'll help someone.